# Allow access to specifically named files when using htaccess password

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in my htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "dev"
AuthUserFile "/home/example/.htpasswds/public_html/example/passwd"
Require valid-user
```

I want to allow access to certain files without the need to enter the password.
These files are any named similar to

```
http://example.com/56B2BB34645F8763C7DC8ADEDC34A0BD.txt
http://example.com/94B2AC8513F8791C7DC8AABFE3DDA0AC.txt
```

and also any .txt files where the name contains

```
"Comodo DCV"
```

I tried

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "dev"
AuthUserFile "/home/example/.htpasswds/public_html/example/passwd"
<RequireAny>
  <RequireAll>
     # example to allow access to callbacks directory
     #Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/callbacks/.*#
     Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
</RequireAll>
Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

but I just get a 500 error when I try to view a txt file.

Where have I gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these directives to allow for certain filed to be presented with auth:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt$|Comodo\ DCV" ALLOWED=TRUE

AuthType Basic
AuthName "dev"
AuthUserFile /home/example/.htpasswds/public_html/example/passwd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=ALLOWED
Satisfy any
```